# Need y position or height Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, vertical-alignment

Here is my view in which i want to set in few `UILAbels`, one `UITableView`, One `UIImageView` and one spacer view. Here is the image

[image]

I have added the vertical spacing between `UIImageView` and Top layout guide and then added vertical spacing of standard value between the `UIImageView`, first `UILabel`, `UITableView`,Country Button, SpacerView , second `UILabel` and info button, then i added vertical spacing between info button and bottom layout guide. To adjust ,u views vertically when device screen changes i added the blue color spacer view and set its vertical content hugging and vertical compression resistance property to 1 so that the spacer view shrinks when i switch to smaller screen and i gets more space when i go to big screen.

Now i am getting errors that i have not given Y position or height to these view, but guess that these views should get the Y position because i am giving them all the constraints to calculate the Y position. Any idea why i am still getting this error and also how spacer view get more space or shrinks accordingly.

Comment: Each of your items; image view etc, all need height constraints to help auto layout figure where they go.  You will also most likely need some constraint in the horizontal as well.

Comment: But if i specify fixed height for UITableView lets say height constraint = 200, then i will work on some screens and may be for smaller screen it will take so much space that other view my go out of the screen.

Comment: That is true, so either work with a smaller table view or you can put everything in a scroll view.  Or make the image view a bit smaller.  You only have a picture two labels and two buttons, you should be able to fit them all with the tableview.